# Count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable error, how to fix?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Trying to move my PHP code from another project into Laravel.

Seems to have an issue with this line of code:

```
<h6><span class="label label-info">@php if (count($Players) == 0){echo "There is no one online";} else {echo "There is currently ". count( $Players ) . "/". $Info[ 'MaxPlayers' ]. " users online";}@endphp</span></h6>
```

Spits back this error here

`count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable`

Here is my php code:

```
$Map    = Array([3]);
$Rules   = Array( );
$Players = Array( );


try
{
    $Query->Connect( SQ_SERVER_ADDR, SQ_SERVER_PORT, SQ_TIMEOUT, SQ_ENGINE );
    $Info    = $Query->GetInfo( );
    $Players = $Query->GetPlayers( );
    $Rules   = $Query->GetRules( );
}
```

Comment: please provide code of your GetPlayers() function?

Comment: $Players obviously don't return an array or an object. Maybe it returns NULL? Based the info you have given us, that's just a qualified guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an object to an array. in Laravel you can use toArray() function.
in PHP 

`$array = (array) $yourObject;`

Answer (score 0):

This is not laravel problem.In PHP 7.3 a new function was added is_countable, specifically to address the E_WARNING issue and the prevalence of applications adopting `is_array($var) || $var instanceof \Countable` in their code.

So if $Players is null, you get an error. Quick way: (array)$Players. Right way:

```
if (!isset($Players) OR !is_array(($Players)) OR count($Players) == 0)
```

BTW if you re using blade please use directives. So dont use @php

```
@if (!isset($Players) OR !is_array(($Players)) OR count($Players) == 0)
There is no one online
@else
There is currently {{ count( $Players ) }}/{{ $Info[ 'MaxPlayers' ] }} users online
@endif
```

Comment: Is this help to you?